# Postgres Function To Update Column By Data Type of Text

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create a function in Postgres to find all columns in a schema (the schema is a text variable which the user can pass in) with a text data type, loop through each returned record and then update the text column with specific data.

Here is my sample code for a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_text_columns_newline(target_schema text)
RETURNS void  
AS $$
DECLARE
r      information_schema.columns%ROWTYPE;   
sql text := ' ';
BEGIN

FOR r IN
    select table_schema, table_name, column_name
    from information_schema.columns
    where upper(data_type) = 'TEXT'
    and UPPER(table_schema) = target_schema 
LOOP

_sql = _sql + ' UPDATE ' || r.table_schema || '.' || r.table_name || ' SET   ' || r.column_name || ' =  REPLACE(r.column_name, _new_line_character, CHR(10));';                

END LOOP;

EXECUTE _sql;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The loop doesn't seem to return the values from the query and my _sql statement is always null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here is `UPPER(table_schema) = target_schema` in your query.

Another place in your function is `REPLACE(r.column_name,`. If I am not wrong this is in your text string. so when you execute it, database will find the column name `column_name` of table `r`, and of course it is not exists.

And I can't find where is `_new_line_character` definition. Maybe you miss it.

I temporary fix it as follow

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_text_columns_newline(target_schema text)
    RETURNS void  
    AS $$
    DECLARE
              r      information_schema.columns%ROWTYPE;   
              _sql text := ' ';
              _new_line_character varchar;
    BEGIN

    FOR r IN
        select table_schema, table_name, column_name
        from information_schema.columns
        where upper(data_type) = 'TEXT'
        and UPPER(table_schema) = upper(target_schema)
    LOOP

    _sql = _sql + ' UPDATE ' || quote_ident(r.table_schema) || '.' || quote_ident(r.table_name) || ' SET   ' || quote_ident(r.column_name) || ' =  REPLACE(' || quote_ident(r.column_name) || ', ' || quote_literal(_new_line_character) || ', CHR(10));';                

    END LOOP;

    EXECUTE _sql;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

About `quote_ident` and `quote_literal` please find more information [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)

Comment: Thank you. That helped. I forgot to add the upper(target_schema). Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Make upper on both side of condition

```
UPPER(table_schema) = UPPER(target_schema)
```

Comment: Thank you. That helped. I forgot to add the upper(target_schema). Appreciate it.